# 'File#renameTo()' does not work in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to rename an existing file using `File#renameTo()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

The following code represents what I am trying to do:

```
public class RenameFileDirectory {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new RenameFileDirectory();
    }

    public RenameFileDirectory() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User-PC\\Desktop\\Nouveau dossier2\\file.png");
        File desFile = new File ("C:\\Users\\User-PC\\Desktop\\Nouveau dossier2\\file2.png");

        if (file.renameTo(desFile)) {
            System.out.println("successful rename");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *But it seems not working* - how is not working?

Comment: If I clean your pseudo-code up into real code, it works fine for me.  You need to be more clear about what, exactly, is not working.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In the console it print me error and not successful rename

Comment: Maybe the file to rename is opened or used by your OS. look it

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) instead. If you read the javadocs for [renameTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29), it states that:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

Comment: Advantage of `move` is that it clearly informs us about problem by throwing specific exception instead of returning false.